# Is there a way to determine what application/process is supposedly using a file/folder?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

There is a stubborn folder in my trash bin that apparently cannot be deleted because "something is using it". I know how to force empty the trash bin, but rather than doing it, I'd like to know exactly **who is using this file**.

Is there a way to determine what application/process is supposedly using a file/folder?

Mac OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the lsof command will show you that.
Open a termin and type "lsof [folder name]" and the command and process id should be listed.

Answer (score 1):

Trash is special - often the file isn't open.

1. Restart to close all files (the system almost never opens a file that's in trash)
2. Empty again
3. Force empty - hold alt/option and empty trash

Worst case, you can use `lsof` but since the trash could be an external drive or an internal drive or a user item - the "trash" is a combination of several locations.

```
sudo lsof ~/.Trash/ /.Trashes/
```